# Opening CSV file using Scanner in Java

Tags: java, csv, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to use File and Scanner in Java to open a CSV file but I can't get it to open using Scanner. Attached below is the code, any ideas?
The relevant code is in the parseFile function

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


    public class CIS350HW1 {

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            boolean quit = false;
            int year = 0;
            while(quit == false){
                printMenu();
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                String str = sc.next().toUpperCase();
                System.out.println(str);
                if (str.equals("Q")) {
                    System.out.println("Good bye");
                    quit = true;
                }
                else if (str.equals("3")) {
                    parseFile(args[0], Integer.parseInt(str), year);
                }
                else if (str.equals("2") || str.equals("1")) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter the year: "); //remember might not be println
                        try { 
                        year = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
                    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                        System.out.print("Invalid formatted input. ");
                    }
                    if (year < 1920 || year > 2010){
                        System.out.println("Not a valid year.");
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                    parseFile(args[0], Integer.parseInt(str), year);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("That is not a valid selection.");
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * prints the menu options to the consul.
         */
        public static void printMenu() {
            System.out.println("Welcome to the Oscars database!");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Please make your selection:");
            System.out.println("1: Search for best picture award winner by year");
            System.out.println("2: Search for best picture award nominees by year");
            System.out.println("3: Search for actor/actress nominations by name");
            System.out.println("Q: Quit");
        }

        public static void parseFile(String args, int n, int year) {
            File file = new File(args);
            Scanner input = null;
            try {
                input = new Scanner(file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Could not open the file for some reason.");
            }


            while(input.hasNext()) {
                String nextLine = input.nextLine();
                String token[] =  nextLine.split(",");
                if (n == 1) {
                    String tempYear[] = token[0].split(" ");
                    if (Integer.parseInt(tempYear[0]) == year 
                            && token[1].equals("Best Picture") 
                            && token[3].equals("YES")) {
                        System.out.println(token[2]);
                    }
                }
            }

            input.close();
        }

    }
```

Note that the code doesn't do anything yet, trying to figure out why the try/catch never works.
Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by 'never works'?

Comment: The error message I wrote "Could not open the file for some reason." always prints and causes a Exception thread in main

Comment: well then it did not find the file. how do you pass the filename to your program?

Comment: I tried both as an argument and hard coding it. The file is in the same folder as the program.

Comment: It can't find the file. Are you using absolute or relative path for the file? Also  make sure you use the right slash character in the file path

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. In general it has worked for me if I just used the file name in the new File()

Answer (score 0):

If you are using command line to run your program (java CIS350HW1 file.csv) then the file must be in the same folder.

But if you run your program from an IDE (Eclipse or another) then your file must be in the classpath of your project.